# Twitter bind event after tweet ( twttr.events.bind ) Not Working

Tags: twitter

I have this simple code That is suppose to alert "I just Tweeted", does not seem to work, i have tried all examples. Even visited this link for help https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/671 but still never worked.

```
<script>

function alertAfterTweet() {
  alert('I just Tweeted')
}

//Bind the custom function with twitter event
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
  twttr.events.bind('click', alertAfterTweet);
});

function jsTweet() {
   var urlTW = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Text&url=http://example.com";
   window.open(urlTW, "", "toolbar=0, status=0, width=650, height=360");
}</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="jsTweet();">Tweet</a>

</script>
```

Please any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1.First include twitter api

```
<script>window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
    var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src= "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function (f) { t._e.push(f) } });
  }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));</script>
```

2.Create the share button using the twitter API and then bind the event (it looks like you want to bind tweet not click):

```
twttr.ready(function(twttr) {
    twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
        'your url',
        document.getElementById('your-element-id'), {
            url: 'your url',
            count: 'none',
            text: 'your text',
            size: 'large',
            hashtags: 'your hashtag'
        }).then(function(el) {
        console.log("Twitter Button created.")
    });
    twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
        //add ur post tweet stuff here 
        console.log('tweet');
    });

});
```

There are many options you can set using the API. for more info:

Javascript: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript

Events: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events

By the way, you can also create the button this way:

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share"
  data-related="twitterdev"
  data-size="large"
  data-count="none">
Tweet
</a>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Does this work in IE11?  I tested similar code and callback never gets called.

Comment: That is a very painful question... IE does not trigger tweet events as well as windows phone.

From Twitter:
"Note that no all browsers trigger events, and if a user chooses to use a native application rather than a Web Intent to complete their interaction you may not get an event for the action. Click events on widgets should always function."

You can also implement the app post: create a twitter app, and with  server side scripting, using the client and secret app key, post on their behalf. this works on all platform of course. 
Please let me know if you need more information about that.

Comment: Thanks! More info would be great (or just a link). I'm curious how this would work from a implementation point of view.

Comment: I'm following the "Detect Events for Web Analytics" example found here: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events, however as mentioned, the bound 'tweet' event callback never gets called in IE11.

Comment: Try this example in IE. It doesn't work for some reason. This is the premise of what I'm trying to accomplish. http://jsfiddle.net/n8ueF/

Comment: Kevin, to result to a server side solution (which is needed if you want to post and image on behalf of a user), I used PHP:
I used this library: 

https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

you will need to create an app with twitter:

http://apps.twitter.com/
set the right permissions, and copy the client and secret keys to the config.php in the library above. than you can post easily.
after the twitter post you can redirect or do anything else you need.

Comment: is it possible to fire tweet event after tweet successful (not on tweet dialog open) ?